# Invoking a function from another which has the same number of inputs and outputs

Tags: matlab

I want to call a function in Matlab using another one, which has the same number of inputs and outputs. In fact, those inputs and outputs have the same name.

Example:

```
function [a,b] = gettwo(matrix,string,varargin)
    [a,b] = getone(matrix,string,varargin{:});
end
```

This code produces the following error:

```
Error in getone(line 3)
aux = 'matrix(varargin{:})';

Output argument "b" (and maybe others) not assigned during
call to "C:\Users\baister\Documents\MATLAB\soft\getone.m>getone".

Error in results (line 4)
[a,b] = getone(matrix,string,varargin{:});
```

How should I wrap `getone`?

(The definitive function will have more lines than those shown in this post.)

Thanks.

Comment: The wrapping itself looks correct - `getone` however seems to produce only one output, not two.

Comment: `getone` produces one or two values depending on `string`. I want `gettwo` to act this way too. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general wrapping for variable number of outputs should work like this:

```
function [varargout] = gettwo(matrix,string,varargin)
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = getone(matrix,string,varargin{:});
end
```

You'll get the same error as above though, in case you do

```
[a,b] = gettwo(...);
```

and `getone` returns only 1 argument.